Django Channels: Maintaining WebSocket Authentication Across Multiple Consumers
I am developing a dashboard using Django Channels and have implemented two WebSocket consumers—UserConsumer and RequestConsumer—to handle user authentication and requests, respectively.
Problem
After successfully logging in through UserConsumer, the session is not shared with RequestConsumer. As a result, the second WebSocket connection (RequestConsumer) detects the user as unauthenticated and immediately closes the connection.
Implementation Details
Authentication in UserConsumer:
Users authenticate via an OTP code sent to their mobile number.
The login method saves the session using self.scope["session"].save().
class UserConsumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()

    async def user_login(self, content):
        verify_code = self.scope.get("verify_code")
        code = content.get("code")
        mobile = self.scope.get("mobile")
        if mobile and verify_code and code == verify_code:
            user = await load_user_by_mobile(mobile)
            del self.scope["verify_code"]
            await login(self.scope, user)
            await database_sync_to_async(self.scope["session"].save)()
            await self.send_json({"code": 200})
        else:
            await self.send_json({"code": 400})

Session Validation in RequestConsumer:
class RequestConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.user = self.scope['user']
        if self.user.is_authenticated:
            await self.accept()
        else:
            await self.close()

ASGI Application Configuration:
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    "http": django_asgi_app,
    "websocket": AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([
                path("user/", UserConsumer.as_asgi()),
                path("requests/", RequestConsumer.as_asgi()),
            ])
        )
    ),
})

Session Settings:
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.db'
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'sessionid'
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True

Client Test Script:
const socket1 = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/user/");

socket1.onmessage = (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (data.code === 200) {
    const socket2 = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8000/requests/");
  }
};

Observations

The user_login method works, and the user is authenticated within
UserConsumer.
However, when the second WebSocket (RequestConsumer) connects, the
user is no longer recognized as authenticated, and the socket closes.
No session cookies appear in the browser, raising concerns about
session persistence across consumers.

Key Questions

How can I persist authentication across multiple WebSocket
connections using Django Channels?

Should cookies or headers be explicitly sent to the browser for
session management in WebSockets?

Is there an issue with the middleware configuration or session
handling in this implementation?


Any help in resolving this would be greatly appreciated!
